# difficulty installing hpricot in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and i have an assignment to use hpricot. I have tried to install hpricot gem and I get error messages. extconf.rb failed.  Could not create makefile. Check the mkmf.log. But I cannot find mkmf.log.

I checked the other answers and tried to install using gem install hpricot-platform=mswin32. that didnt work either.

Should I reinstall Ruby version 1.8?

Comment: "I am using Ruby 1.92. My next assignment is to use hpricot." is a pretty poor question title. I've modified it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing native Ruby extensions on Windows for Jekyll](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3640298/), [Problem installing gem on Windows Vista 32-bit](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4012343/) [What to do about failed native extension builds in gem on Windows?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3155707/) and dozens of others.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I tried and installed devkit.

Answer (score 0):

Is hpricot required? Nokogiri should work for you, and IIRC, it has a compatibility layer so that it can act as a drop-in replacement for hpricot if needed.

Comment: It is for an assignment. The professor wants us to use hpricot. I checked the link on devkit and installed that. Now hpricot seems to work - but I get an incompatible character encodings error : UTF-8 and ASCII- 8BIT. Am I still missing something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you get the error? Do you know how Ruby 1.9.2 handles character encodings? Here's a link, you can google for more info if you need: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string